# Shake the device to launch an application in Android

Tags: android, shake

How can we launch a application by just shaking the device? I want to do something similar to the app "Appshaker".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From an activity, you can use the `SensorManager` to detect a shake, then react to that shake. That is what AppShaker does. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Sensor/Shaker) demonstrating one way to detect a shake.

Comment: Was looking for that exact thing! Thanks. Cool app btw

Comment: @MahadevanSreenivasan please check this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319601/shake-phone-to-launch-app