# how to invoke google map on shaking in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

i just want to make an application regarding Google maps , when some shake the device Google map application will invoke and send current location via message to other person...

i have merge google maps in my app

and

i am looking for some implementation regarding shaking event?

Comment: Use accelerometer sensor to catch the shaking event and inside that write your logic

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803370/shake-the-device-to-launch-an-application-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android platform supports three broad categories of sensors:

**Motion sensors**
These sensors measure acceleration forces and rotational forces along three axes. This category includes accelerometers, gravity sensors, gyroscopes, and rotational vector sensors.

**Environmental sensors**
These sensors measure various environmental parameters, such as ambient air temperature and pressure, illumination, and humidity. This category includes barometers, photometers, and thermometers.

**Position sensors**
These sensors measure the physical position of a device. This category includes orientation sensors and magnetometers.
[See Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html).

You can get of more useful stuff out of this [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/info_zybotech/android-accelerometer-sensor-tutorial).

Have look at this [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Sensor/Shaker).