# Android: Start recording video with the activity without any kind of user interface with specified size and quality

Tags: android, video, camera

I want to start video recording immediately with a shake, preferably without turning on the screen or showing anything on screen (no user interface except shake to start recording). Can anyone provide an example?

I am currently at the point where shaking device starts my videorecord.class activity. I want to include "no interface video recording" within this activity.

Comment: Friend refer to these sites it will help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319601/shake-device-to-launch-app